# how i can install arch-linux-x64 on UEFI-32bit

Tags: linux, ubuntu, arch-linux, grub, uefi

I have a `tablet laptop` with `intel Atom` with `CPU x64bit`, and `UEFI 32bit`.
the system can't be able to boot from the `UEFI` system in `arch Linux`, because `arch-linux` does not include some `files` in `/BOOT/EFI/*32.efi`

## UPDATE in 2022

- I install `void-linux`
- I create a new partition
- I download/extract `archlinux.tar.xz` to this partition
- chroot to `arch-linux`
- mount `boot/EFI
- installing `grub 32bit` and running it

for `artix-linux` it does not have `artix.tar.zx` so crate this tar file from `artix.iso`

Comment: Have you tried [Booting 64-bit kernel on 32-bit UEFI](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#Booting_64-bit_kernel_on_32-bit_UEFI)?

Comment: yes, already treid for arch but not work,  32-UFFI not able to run /BOOT/EFI/*64 from usb

Answer (score 1):

hey so i might be late but there is actually this

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GRUB#Installation

and there it basically says to switch out `x86_64-efi` with `i386-efi` to install a 32 bit EFI but this only works for 64 bit cpus locked to 32 bit UEFI.

If you are using archfi to install arch, you can do this after you finish the whole installation, just quit without rebooting, mount the partitions and install the grub.

if the grub isnt installing and you might be getting an airootfs error then do this

```
arch-chroot /mnt /bin/bash
```

and repeat from mounting and it should work

this is much simpler and it worked for me on the first try